# What kind of caches are cleared automatically after product edit in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, cache, magento2.4

After reading some comments on the ticket [magento2/issues/25670](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/25670) what I can understand is Magento 2 creates/stores a tag for each entity which is modified. For example if a product is modified it's tag is stored and cache of that entity is cleared automatically. But I am not sure if my understanding is correct.

My questions are:

- How this tag is stored? Does it store the product id/sku of the product which was modified or it stores the entity name only (ex: catalog_product)?
- Where this tag info is stored? In db/file?
- What kind of caches are cleared on product edit? Does it clear cache of a particular entity or it clears full page cache? Any other caches are cleared on product edit?
- These caches are cleared on product save only or on admin product page load also?

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature!

Magento 2 out of the box will clear correct caches on the frontend depending on cache tags. Each entity that impacts the cache will have it's own tags. Once a product is saved all of the pages on which that product appears will be cleared. No need to flush the cache.

See more info here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/cache/cache-priv-inval.html

> The Magento application enables you to clear cached content immediately after a entity changes. We use an IdentityInterface to link entities in the application with cached content and to know what cache to clear when an entity changes.

Comment: Can you please answer the 4 questions that I have asked like how/where the tag information is stored? You have mentioned once a product is saved all of the pages on which that product appears will be cleared. How cache is cleared for a particular page? For example, let's say product is assign to category "Test", and if the product is modified, will it clear cache for this category only or all?